# Watir crashes if I loop several times on the same pages

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, geckodriver

I've automated the upload of some evidences to a compliance intranet where I work (I cannot provide details) with watir.

I've done something as simple as opening a firefox session to that intranet and than a loop that goes through each server I pass as command line argument. It searches for that server using a form does that clicks it has to do in order to upload the evidence (a zip file).

```
ARGV.each do|server|
  shotname = "#{download_directory}/foo_#{server}.png"
    b.goto 'https://compl.intra.secret.com/index.php'

    l = b.link text: 'Systems'
    l.wait_until_present
    l.exists?
    l.click

  ....
  ....
end
```

As soon as I execute the script with few servers, CPU goes at 100%, but it reaches the end without issues, but if I pass about 20 servers as my arguments, ruby crashes really bad with this stacktrace

```
stack backtrace:: Failed to find value field (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
        from    0:           0x4edb3c - backtrace::backtrace::trace::hc4bd56a2f176de7e
        from    1:           0x4edb72 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he3b2a15d39027c46
        from    2:           0x4409a1 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h81babdd86c977032
        from    3:           0x44b2c7 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteSession::response::ha4a2fbbdd9abe262
        from    4:           0x429f1a - <webdriver::server::Dispatcher<T, U>>::run::h2119c674d7b88193
        from    5:           0x4029b9 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h21d98a9ff86d4c25
        from    6:           0x40be65 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h5cff0c9b18cfdbba
        from    7:           0x5e6a6c - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
        from                         at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:99
        from    8:           0x41eb22 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::h413eb1d9d9f1c473
        from    9:           0x5df13b - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>
        from                         at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:692
        from                          - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread
        from                         at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21
        from                          - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start
        from                         at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84
        from /home/antenore/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'
```

My code it's less than acceptable, but I was wondering if it may be also a bug and if you have any advices in order to optimize a loop like the one I've described.

I didn't try to run the script without the headless extension.

Thanks a lot!!!

System:

```
Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six)
```

Gems used/installed:

```
watir (6.10.3)
watir-screenshot-stitch (0.6.5)
headless (2.3.1)
```

Others:

geckodriver 0.19.1
   Firefox 57.0.1

Comment: Have you tried running the script for each server in isolation? Does it crash at the same server every time? Also, what does the assertion in response.rb:69 check for (from your stack trace) ? And could you please  clarify the sentence "It searches for that server using a form does that clicks it has to do in order to pload the evidence (a zip file)." ?

Comment: I believe `watir-webdriver` is deprecated, and thus should not be `require`d by your applications / scripts.

Comment: Also, cursory review of others with similar error messages indicates you might have luck if you are able to update your geckodriver and Firefox versions to the latest available: 0.19.1 and 58.0.1, respectively. Good luck!

Comment: @FrankSchmitt no, it's not a problem with a particular server, but with the number of arguments I pass to my script, like there is a memory leak somwhere, becuase I don't free some resources?

Comment: @Sam I don't require watir-webdriver , sorry I was not clear. I've installed the gem, but it's not used. I've the latest firefox and geckdriver I think, I'll check asap

Comment: @Sam do you really think updating Firefox may help? the geckodriver it's the last one

Comment: @tmow geckodriver and selenium-webdriver bug fixes often suggest some version of geckodriver works best with some version of Firefox. If you can find a canonical list of which work with which, you're better at Google than me.

Comment: @tmow, do you have the ability to try the script using Chrome? It might help identify if there is a browser problem compared to a Watir problem.

Comment: Thanks @Sam . No I think that at the best I've the same Google skills as you. I'll test ASAP .

Comment: @JustinKo no sorry, I don't have one and sincerely Idon't want o...

Comment: @Sam it was the Firefox version, I've updated to Firefox 58.0.1 and I don't have problem anymore. I'll add an answer for those interested. Thanks a lot to all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As advised by the [geckdriver developers](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/master/README.md):

> Support is best in Firefox 55 and greater, although generally the more
>   recent the Firefox version, the better the experience as they have
>   more bug fixes and features. Some features will only be available in
>   the most recent Firefox versions, and we strongly advise using the
>   latest Firefox Nightly with geckodriver.

With the last geckdriver release (my case), is always better to use the last version of Firefox.

The main reason for this, always quoting hteir GitHub README

> geckodriver is not yet feature complete. This means that it does not
>   yet offer full conformance with the WebDriver standard or complete
>   compatibility with Selenium. You can track the implementation status
>   of the latest Firefox Nightly on MDN. We also keep track of known
>   Selenium, remote protocol, and specification problems in our issue
>   tracker.

In fact, in my specific case, updating to Firefox 58.0.1, the latest release available on Fedora 26, fixed my problem.

Therefore, as rule of dumb, you must always use both latest version of geckdriver and Pirefox whenever possible, or at least follows the reccomandations of each [release notes](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) (if any).

Thanks to @Sam @JustinKo and @FrankSchmitt  for their precious support.